# Is it possible to parse a X509 certificate with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, x509

I need to parse a X509 certificate. Specifically I need to find the Policy ID #1 (e.g. when I have a look at the certificate of https://www.apple.com I find somewhere in the Extensions an entry Policy ID #1 (2.16.840...). I need to extract this number.

Until now I tried to use openSSL to do the job, but since I am not really familiar with ObjC or C and the documentation seems to be sparse I failed miserably.

My question now: Is it possible to get this information with the help of Alamofire in Swift? If yes I would be grateful for any tips on how to do this.
If anyone knows how to extract this information in ObjC with openSSL I'm also thankful for any tips.